# Photo Map tip in QGIS 3 on windows

Tags: qgis, windows, qgis-3, windows-10, maptips

How do you display a photo map tip in QGIS 3 on Windows?

As a new user I'm not sure if this is my lack of experience or a bug, so I've tried to simplify it as far as I can:

This is the contents of the Layer Display properties.

[image: Properties -> Display]

```
<div style="width:400;height:400">
<p>test</p>
<div><img src="C:\Local\aa.jpg" width="350" /></div>
</div>
```

and this is how it appears:

[image: Maptip as it appears]

`C:\Local\aa.jpg` is real file I'm using to try to figure out what the problem is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's a forward slash at the end of the file path that looks out of place to me.Try <img src="C:\Local\aa.jpg" width="350"> instead of <img src="C:\Local\aa.jpg" width="350" />

Comment: That is for closing the img tag, which would be necessary in XHTML. I tried taking it out and it made no difference, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Will you add `file:///` before the drive letter `C:` ?

```
<img src="file:///C:/Local/aa.jpg" width="350" />
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I'd previously tried the file:/// thing (and swapping the backslashes to slashes, but hadn't realized that you need 3 slashes, not 2.

Comment: Thanks @sandyscott glad it worked. Yes, me too, tried 2 slashes first, then three by luck.

Comment: This helped me, too. 3 slashes are required for Windows systems. Linux paths already have one at the start. `file:///C:\Users\username\my_photo.jpg`, vs `file:///home/username/my_photo.jpg`.

Comment: Maybe also worth mentioning is that, on Windows at least, it doesn't seem to care about the direction of slashes. I've just tested it with both variations and a combination(ie c:\gis\photos/2019-09-24 12.46.14.jpg works!). That is the way the ImportPhotos plugin formats it in QGIS 3.8.1