# HTML-"Tooltip" (Mouseover) V2 vs V3

Tags: qgis, html

is there a change for HTML-Mouseover (I dont know the exact wording in english-version. German: Anzeigen, Kartenhinweis) between Version 2 and 3? The same code dont work in V3 ;(

```
<div style="width:320;height:250">
<small><small> [%"field_2"%]
<a href="[% field_1 %]/[% field_2 %]"><img src="[% "field_1" %]/[% "field_2" %]" width=300  /></a>
```

[image]

field_1 and field_2 is Path an filename:

[image]

Comment: PS: the link to the image (<a href="[% field_1 %]/[% field_2 %]">) works fine in BOTH versions

Comment: also if I "hard-code" the Image-Link, ist dont work:
<img src="M:/Bilder/Digitalbilder/_2011/2011-09-10_Korfu/2011-09-11_143121_Korfu.jpg" width=300  />

Comment: Yes, referencing to file path to local files have changed in v3.0. Might be related: [Photo Map tip in QGIS 3 on windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274500/photo-map-tip-in-qgis-3-on-windows).